# batch command to check value against a list of values

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file that, depending on the numeric day of the month, will copy files to a particular directory. If the variable is 01 to 07, copy to Week1, if 08 to 14, copy to Week2, etc. I guess there is nothing like an IN command to attempt this.

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%I in (\\01mtsdv130\CMApps\Log\EnhancedLogging\*.*) do (
   set thedate=!folder:~11,2!
   set mydate=!folder:~5,6!

   if "!thedate!"=="01" (
       copy %%I c:\holdlogs\01mtsdv130\"!mydate!"\Week1\
   )
   if "!thedate!"=="02" (
       copy %%I c:\holdlogs\01mtsdv130\"!mydate!"\Week1\
   )

    ... etc
)
```

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Use the [set /a](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) command to calculate the week, but take care leading zeroes are interpreted as octal and thus 08,09 would return an error. Standard way to overcome this is to prefix the 2place number with a one and subtract 100. Where do you define the var `folder`?

Comment: Where does `!folder!` come from? is it always the same value in each loop iteration?

Answer (score 1):

### Here it is all together:

```
@(
  setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  ECHO OFF
)
SET "_Folder=Your folder Goes here"
SET "_TheDate=%_folder:~11,2%"
SET "_MyDate=%_folder:~5,6%"
SET /A "_TheDate#=1!%TheDate% - ( 2%TheDate% - 1%TheDate% )"
SET /A "_TheWeek#=( ( %_TheDate#% + 6 ) / 7) "

FOR %%I IN (
  "\\01mtsdv130\CMApps\Log\EnhancedLogging\*.*"
) DO (
  Copy /B /V /Y "%%~fI" "c:\holdlogs\01mtsdv130\%_MyDate%\Week%_TheWeek#%\"
)
```

### Details / Original post:

Since your weeks are sequential sets you can group them using a division operation by looking for the product of division and call a label or have separate IF code for each.

Now, you don't define the `Folder` variable anywhere, is that supposed to be the same on each go-round?\

If so set it outside your loop!

Since this is set outside, and you get your date values from it, then that all can go outside as well, and you can make your choice about where to copy outside your loop as well.

```
@(
  setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  ECHO OFF
)
SET "_Folder=Your folder Goes here"
SET "_TheDate=%_folder:~11,2%"
SET "_MyDate=%_folder:~5,6%"
```

You'll need to look at the day values without any leading 0s to make some comparisons using that method, this is fairly simple we can save that value as `_TheDate#` in case you need the original.

```
SET /A "_TheDate#=1%TheDate% - ( 2%TheDate% - 1%TheDate% )"
```

Although in your case you can use the more specific `SET /A "_TheDate#=1%TheDate% - 100"` I prefer the more general solution above as it will work for any number of leading 0s which need to be stripped (So long as it is less than the 32bit integer limit in CMD when a 2 is placed in front of it.)

Then we can Get the week:

```
SET /A "_TheWeek#=( ( %_TheDate#% + 6 ) / 7) "
```

Note how we add 6? why? to get you the propper week (  This is because `0/7` through `6/7` will return `0`, but `7/7` will return `1`, however, we want `1/7` through `7/7` to return `1` and `8/7` through `14/7` to return `2` as outlined in your request.  To do so, we add 6 to the initial date value found when doing the check, which causes the actual arithmetic performed on `1/7` through `7/7` to be `7/7` through `14/7`, which will return `1`. and for `8/7` though `14/7` the actual check will be `14/7` through `20/7` and return 2, etc.)

Now it looks like you literally wan to copy into a folder called WEEK1 Week2 3 etc

So this is ready to go using your existing loop:

```
for %%I in (\\01mtsdv130\CMApps\Log\EnhancedLogging\*.*) do (
  copy /B /V /Y "%%~fI" "c:\holdlogs\01mtsdv130\%MyDate%\Week%_Week#%\"
)
```

### Here it is all together:

```
@(
  setlocal
  ECHO OFF
)
SET "_Folder=Your folder Goes here"
SET "_TheDate=%_folder:~11,2%"
SET "_MyDate=%_folder:~5,6%"
SET /A "_TheDate#=1%TheDate% - ( 2%TheDate% - 1%TheDate% )"
SET /A "_TheWeek#=( ( %_TheDate#% + 6 ) / 7) "

FOR %%I IN (
  \\01mtsdv130\CMApps\Log\EnhancedLogging\*.*
) DO (
  Copy /B /V /Y "%%~fI" "c:\holdlogs\01mtsdv130\%_MyDate%\Week%_TheWeek#%\"
)
```

### If you need to get and set the values in each loop iteration:

In this scenario, we'll actually end up using that delayed expansion.

```
@(
  setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  ECHO OFF
)


FOR %%I IN (
  "\\01mtsdv130\CMApps\Log\EnhancedLogging\*.*"
) DO (
  SET "_Folder=Set from something you are looping I suppose?"
  SET "_TheDate=%_folder:~11,2%"
  SET "_MyDate=%_folder:~5,6%"
  SET /A "_TheDate#=1!TheDate! - ( 2!TheDate! - 1!TheDate! )"
  SET /A "_TheWeek#=( ( !_TheDate#! + 6 ) / 7) "
  Copy /B /V /Y "%%~fI" "c:\holdlogs\01mtsdv130\!_MyDate!\Week!_TheWeek#!\"
)
```

Comment: +1 You've given me a fix for my problem of parentheses in the `set/a` within a loop/if statement (never thought of double-quoting it... not sure why). Can I ask what's the benefit of the `@(...)` construct at the top, instead of just `@echo off` and `setlocal...` on separate lines? Or is it just stylistic?

Comment: @TripeHound: IMHO the `@(...)` construct just confuses beginners and have no benefit...  **`:(`**

Comment: I prefer to change my environment after using the SETLOCAL command which means that the changes will be reverted on an end local.  The and I don't want to echo either to the screen.  Anything inside parenthesis is evaluated at the same time in CMD, and so if you use @ in front of a parenthesis everything will be silenced, the same as using @ in front of each command.  It adds 1 extra character, but I often put my variable declarations in there as well to sort of section them off.

Comment: @BenPersonick: That is Ok but, what is the benefit of doing this way? As I said, this syntax is confusing and Batch files are instrinsically confusing, so you _should_ write lines as simple as possible in the benefit of beginners... Just my opinion.

Comment: @Aacini  Its using the tools that CMD gave us.  As I said I like to prefer that over `@ SETLOCAL` `@ECHO OFF` as it is one additional character to write `@( )`  looks nicer, and allow syou to put your variable declarations there to keep them together when you want to.  It also opens up the discussion about how parenthesis works occasionally if they are newer, and if they are used to other programming languages and even how English syntax generally works or math, then they will generally understand that things in the parenthesis go together, so I can just explain what the @ does. :)

Comment: @TripeHound Oops forgot to tag you the first Time I replied: I prefer to change my environment after using the `SETLOCAL` command which means that the changes will be reverted on an `ENDLOCAL` and I don't want to `echo` either command to the screen so I woudl have to preface each with `@`. Anything inside parenthesis `()` is evaluated at the same time in CMD, and so if you use `@` in front of a parenthesis everything will be silenced, the same as using `@` in front of each command. It adds 1 extra character, but I often put my variable declarations in there as well to sort of section them off.

Comment: If you put `@ECHO OFF` in first line and `SETLOCAL` in second one, then the second line does not require the `@`. BTW, this is the way that practically every Batch file published is written. Of course, you may use a non-standard syntax if you wish...  **`:/`**

Comment: @TripeHound  Also I initially had "_Week" instead of "_TheWeek" at a couple of spots which I cleared up.  I want to draw attention to one other thing I took into consideration the date you woudl liek to be used for a given week, I now notice that a couple similar answers have since been posted that do not take that into account, so I put a bit more emphasis on why we add 6 to the Week.  one final bit you can combine the check for the week number for the Day number if you don't need that variable again but I left it separate as I though ti was more clear. :)  Glad to help! :)

Comment: @Aacini `I explained why I don't do that already.` this is the way that practically every Batch file published is written `That does make it better or standard, just that it is common.  That is not a "Best Practice" of any sort, and yes, you can write them your way too so I don't know why you are pestering me over pointlessness.` If you put @ECHO OFF in first line and SETLOCAL in second one, then the second line does not require the @. BTW, this is the way that practically every Batch file published is written. Of course, you may use a non-standard syntax if you wish... :/ – Aacini 47 secs ago

Comment: @BenPersonick Appreciate your responses... I've been batch programming for more years than I care to remember but am constantly finding (and on the lookout for) new tricks... My final question: is there a specific situation where having `echo off` _after_ the `setlocal` is of benefit? (Other than keeping all "environment-changing commands" together)

Comment: @TripeHound  No, there is no benefit, either way, it's a matter of preference only, there is no best practice to it, my apology if I came off as saying it mattered one way or the other, my point to Aacini was supposed to be that it does not matter, and I think most people can understand the usage of the parenthesis in the general concept that it is a grouping, and may not know that @ just silences any cmd, some people think it is ECHO specific.  There are also times I will not use ECHO OFF, but I still usually want to silence my initial variable setup, which is how the concept started for me.

Comment: @KathyLori Take a look when you have a moment I was talking with TripeHound thinking he had written the question, my apology.  Do you have any questions on this answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the `LEQ` (less than or equal) operator (see `IF /?`):

```
if !thedate! LEQ 07 (
    set week=1
) else if !thedate! LEQ 14 (
    set week=2
) else if !thedate! LEQ 21 (
    set week=3
) else if !thedate! LEQ 28 (
    set week=4
) else if !thedate! LEQ 31 (
    set week=5
) else (
    REM handle invalid filename
)
copy %%I c:\holdlogs\01mtsdv130\"!mydate!"\Week!week!\
```

Or, building on [@LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) suggestion:

```
set /a day0 = 1!thedate! - 101
set /a week = day0 / 7 + 1
```

To avoid the "octal problem" we prefix the two-digit number with 1. We then subtract `101` (not 100) so that we get a zero-based day number. This allows the division by 7 in the following line to work. *Note*: we don't need `!` around `day0` because `set /a` will read environment variables directly. However, we *do* need it for `!thedate!` because we want to make a text-replacement so `08` becomes `108` before letting `set /a` loose on it.

In *theory* we should be able to do something like `set /a week = ( 1!thedate! - 101 ) / 7 + 1` to calculate the week in one go. However, it appears the parentheses conflict with those of the `if` and/or `for` statements.

Comment: you can overcome the parentheses problem by quoting: `set /a "week = ( 1!thedate! - 101 ) / 7 + 1"`. The parentheses are save, because they are inside a quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

All that's needed is a little mathematical gymnastics:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%I in (\\01mtsdv130\CMApps\Log\EnhancedLogging\*.*) do (
   set thedate=!folder:~11,2!
   set mydate=!folder:~5,6!

   SET /a wdate=(((1!thedate! - 1^)%% 100^) / 7^) + 1
   copy %%I c:\holdlogs\01mtsdv130\"!mydate!"\Week!wdate!\

)
```

Add 100 to the date by stringing `1` before the daynumber, then subtract 1 giving 100..130

Get mod-100 of this; 0..30

integer-divide by 7 = 0..4

add 1=1..5

Here's a simple test for each day

REM

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /L %%a IN (101,1,131) DO (
 SET "xdate=%%a"
 SET "xdate=!xdate:~-2!"
 SET /a wdate=(((1!xdate! -1^)%% 100^) / 7^) + 1
 ECHO !xdate! !wdate!
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to achieve this. Here there are two forms:

```
rem Initialize data: days in each week
set "week1=01 02 03 04 05 06 07"
set "week2=08 09 10 11 12 13 14"
set "week3=15 16 17 18 19 20 21"
set "week4=22 23 24 25 26 27 28"
set "week5=29 30 31"


rem Main loop goes here...

rem Transform "mydate" into "%%d", required to process nested delayed expansions
for %%d in (!mydate!) do (

   rem Process each week
   for %%w in (1,1,5) do (

      rem Next line is equivalent to "if mydate in week%%w"
      if "!week%%w:%%d=!" neq "!week%%w!" copy %%I Week%%w

   )

)
```

In previous method, the `"!week%%w:%%d=!"` part try to remove the mydate from the week. If the result is *different*, then such a mydate *do* exists in the week.

Another, more direct method:

```
rem Initialize data: corresponding week for each date, that is:
rem week01=1 week02=1 ... week07=1   week08=2 week09=2 ... week14=2   ...   week29=5 week30=5 week31=5

rem Initialize day counter
set "i=100"
rem Process 5 weeks
for /L %%w in (1,1,5) do (
   rem Process 7 days per week
   for /L %%d in (1,1,7) do (
      set /A i+=1
      set "week!i:~1!=%%w"
   )
)


rem Main loop goes here...

rem Transform "mydate" into "%%d", required to process nested delayed expansions
for %%d in (!mydate!) do (

   rem Copy file into corresponding week
   copy %%I Week!week%%d!

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that is based on a loop-up list like:

> ```cmd
>   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  5  5  5
> [01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 34 35 36 37 38 39 30 31]
> ```

The second line in brackets denotes the list position per item, so the list item is the week number and the position is the day. (Of course some maths like `day % 7` would be easier, but I just want to demonstrate usage of such a list using [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) and its `tokens` option in a dynamic way.)

So this is the code (see all the explanatory `rem` remarks):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Run `for` loop while delayed expansion is disabled:
for %%I in ("\\01mtsdv130\CMApps\Log\EnhancedLogging\*.*") do (
    rem // Store currently iterated item:
    set "ITEM=%%I"
    rem // Enable delayed expansion now:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "thedate=!folder:~11,2!"
    set "mydate=!folder:~5,6!"

    rem // Get week number for the current day in a sub-routine:
    call :GET_WEEK WEEK !thedate!

    rem // Create destination directory in advance, suppress error message:
    2> nul md "C:\holdlogs\01mtsdv130\!mydate!\Week!WEEK!"
    rem /* Apply delayed expansion here (no `%%I`) to maintain `!` and `^`;
    rem    quote full paths rather than partial ones or single elements: */
    ECHO copy "!ITEM!" "C:\holdlogs\01mtsdv130\!mydate!\Week!WEEK!"
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B


:GET_WEEK  <rtn_week>  <val_day>
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    set "DAY=%~2"
    rem // Remove leading zeros in a flexible way, independent on total width:
    for /F "tokens=* delims=0 eol=0" %%Z in ("%DAY%") do set "DAY=%%Z"
    rem // Convert remainder to a true signed 32-bit integer value:
    set /A "DAY+=0"
    rem // Avoid number to be zero or less:
    if %DAY% leq 0 set "DAY=32"
    rem /* Get the week from a list while the day points to the item position;
    rem    for a dynamic `tokens` option delayed expansion must be disabled: */
    (
        for /F "tokens=%DAY%" %%W in (
            "1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5"
        ) do endlocal & set "%~1=%%W"
    ) || (endlocal & set "%~1=0")
    exit /B
```

As you can see I made some more modifications each of which is mentioned in the comments as well.

I put an upper-case `ECHO` command in front of `copy` so you can check for the correct destination path. Once you completed doing so just remove `ECHO` to actually copy files.